# Conditionally Remove Variables after referencing other data in R

Tags: r

I am trying to remove values from a data matrix in R using a metric, but I'd like them eliminated only with the caveat they are not present in other .csv files or data matrices.

I can eliminate values from a data frame using a Subset function, but that is only within the same data file.  I'd essentially like to search the other data files and keep the row if it is present in another data file.

```
Data 1
ID     Value     Value 2     Elimination Metric
1       23         23            0.05
2       34         45            0.09              
3       89         11          **0.12**              
4       76         17          **0.11**        
5       01         22            0.02
```

So if I have my metric threshold to keep only samples below 0.1, then I'd want to eliminate ID 3 & 4 from my data frame.  But If they are present in data set 2, I'd want to keep them

```
Data 2
    ID     Value     Value 2     Elimination Metric
    1       23         23            0.020
    2       34         45            0.018              
    3       89         11          **0.12**              
    4       76         17          **0.09**        
    5       01         22            0.03
```

So data 2 has 3 above my threshold, and 4 below.  So I want to get rid of ID 3, but keep 4.

Any suggestions?  I'll be comparing this across numerous data sets.

Thanks in advance, I've searched around and have not been able to pull out any good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge function capabilities e.g. :

```
# example data (N.B. I've added one row to data1 not present in data2)
data1 <- read.csv(text=
'ID,Value,Value 2,Elimination Metric
1,23,23,0.05
2,34,45,0.09              
4,76,17,0.11        
5,01,22,0.02
3,89,11,0.12    
5,02,34,0.20', check.names=F)
data2 <- read.csv(text=
'ID,Value,Value 2,Elimination Metric
1,23,23,0.05
2,34,45,0.09              
3,89,11,0.12              
4,76,17,0.09        
5,01,22,0.02', check.names=F)

# merge the 2 data.frame's using ID,Value and Value 2 as keys,
# * all.x=T means all the rows of data1 will be present and joined 
#   with the equal row of data2
# * sort=F guarantees that the original data1 order is kept
df <- merge(x=data1,y=data2,by=c("ID","Value","Value 2"),all.x=T,sort=F)

# replace NAs (i.e. rows present only in data1) 
# with a invalid value for the filter (i.e. > 0.1)
df[is.na(df[,"Elimination Metric.y"]),"Elimination Metric.y"] <- 1

# construct the boolean filter
filter <- df[,"Elimination Metric.x"] < 0.1 | df[,"Elimination Metric.y"] < 0.1

# filter the merged data.frame
dfFilt <- df[filter,]
# or if you prefer you can directly filter your original data1
data1Filt <- data1[filter,]
```

Results :

```
> dfFilt
  ID Value Value 2 Elimination Metric.x Elimination Metric.y
1  1    23      23                 0.05                 0.05
2  2    34      45                 0.09                 0.09
3  4    76      17                 0.11                 0.09
4  5     1      22                 0.02                 0.02

> data1Filt
  ID Value Value 2 Elimination Metric
1  1    23      23               0.05
2  2    34      45               0.09
3  4    76      17               0.11
4  5     1      22               0.02
```

N.B.

It is not recommended to have invalid column names (e.g. name with spaces) in data.frame's. You should consider to rename `"Value 2"` to something like `"Value2"`, `"Value.2"` or `"Value_2"`.

In this way, for example column selection using `$` will be much easier, i.e. :

```
data1$Value2
```

instead of :

```
data1$`Value 2`
```